# PHP Facebook SDK / Graph API - reading posts from public fan page not working

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, user-permissions

I want to write a small personal app (not necessary public) for my own use which will read out Posts from public fanpages.
Anything works so far, i'm able to log in and here's my code snippet for retrieving the posts:

```
$pageposts = $fb->get('/'.$page_id.'/posts', $token);
foreach ($pageposts["data"] as $fppost) {
    echo $fppost['message'];
}
```

which is giving me this error:

```
This endpoint requires the 'pages_read_engagement' permission or the 'Page Public Content Access' feature
```

I added `pages_read_engagement` to my login permissions and found out i need to verify my page first for getting that permission.

So i filled out the verification form and submitted it and it was not approved (answer was in german, i translated it):

Not Approved: Access to public content from pages

App verification feedback

It looks like your app isn't quite finished yet. In order for us to test and approve your app, it must be fully functional and reflect the final user experience.

Access to public content from Feedback pages

We have determined that your app's use case is invalid for this entitlement - or is not required to support core app functionality. You can find more information about the use cases that we allow on our “Authorization Reference” and “Features” pages.

Ok .. how can i show the full user experience without getting that `pages_read_engagement` permission?
Or did i miss something / do something wrong?

Comment: Without `pages_read_engagement` you can't. You'll need to show and explain the use-case properly via screencast and will have to share application/website with Facebook Review Team to test the functionality

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/features-reference/page-public-content-access: _“Allowed Usage: Provide competitive benchmark analysis.”_ - if what you intend to achieve does not fall into this narrow category, then you will not get this feature approved for your app. (Unless you cheat/lie in review, and make them believe this _was_ what you intend to do.)

Comment: _“how can i show the full user experience without getting that pages_read_engagement permission?”_ - you can ask any user that has a role in your app for the permission, even before it is approved in review.

Answer (score 1):

You can read on `/feed` intead of `/posts`.
You can find the documents here:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v11.0/page/feed